# Order posts by more than one variable (meta_key and publish date AND time)

Tags: wp-query, order, meta-value

At cascadeoc.org/results I have results sorted by a Custom Field, "event_date_results" which is the date the *event* happened (not the date the post was published). However, when there are multiple results from the *same day*, I'd like to further control post order by *published date and TIME*. How can I add this second orderby filter?

Here's what I have:

```
<?php

    $query = new WP_Query( array(

        'post_type' => 'result',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        //'paged'          => $paged,
        'meta_key'   => 'event_date_results',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'meta_value'    => date('Ymd'),
        'meta_compare'  => '<',
        'date_query'    => array(
            array(
                    'key' => 'date',
                    'value' => date('Ymd'),
                    'compare' => '<', //less than
                    'type' => 'DATETIME'
                )
            ),

        ) );

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this link about "[a more powerful ORDER BY in WordPress 4.0](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/)" and it led me to try this code:

```
        <?php

    $query = new WP_Query( array(

        'post_type' => 'result',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        //'paged'          => $paged,
        'meta_key'   => 'event_date_results',
        'orderby'    => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'post_date' => 'DESC'),
        //'order'      => 'DESC',
        'meta_value'    => date('Ymd'),
        'meta_compare'  => '<',
        'date_query'    => array(
            array(
                    'key' => 'date',
                    'value' => date('Ymd'),
                    'compare' => '<', //less than
                    'type' => 'DATETIME'
                )
            ),

        ) );

    ?>
```

The 'orderby' line is the only thing I changed (and I commented out the other 'DESC' line I had... which I could delete now.)

...don't mind my commented out 'paged' bit... I'm still figuring out how to paginate this as well. ;)